# Python 3 program help. If file_size is 6, then 6 odd numbers ranging from 5 to 19 must be written to file

Tags: python, file, text, import

-opens a file named numbers.txt in write mode.
-generates a random integer named file_size between 4 and 7, inclusive.
writes file_size random integers to numbers.txt, but each random integer must be both between 5 and 19 inclusive and be an odd number. Duplicates are okay.
-each of the random numbers should be written to its own line in numbers.txt.
-This program is not required to generate any output to the screen.
-example ``- if file_size is 6, then 6 odd numbers ranging from 5 to 19 must be written to file.

```
import random 

def main():

    number_file= open('numbers.txt', 'w')

    file_size = random.randint(4,7)



main()
```

Comment: this is all ive got so far. i really need help folks

Comment: Could you show how much you tried yourself and where you got stuck ?

Comment: it really looks like an assignment to me. Please show your attempts at it

Comment: import random 

def main():

 number_file= open('numbers.txt', 'w')

 file_size = random.randint(4,7)

        
 
main()
 This is all i have so far I dont even really understand the instructions too well

Comment: sorry first time user here im not sure how to input my program properly into the comments

Comment: please edit your question... and read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Don't commet the code. Edit the question and post the code there

Comment: Thank you guys for the constructive criticism i would like to be active in this community.

Comment: hint: proceeding with the code, you might want to add a loop within which you generate the random odd numbers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I think your teacher is going to notice how quickly your python skills have improved.
Please research what the `with` statement does. And how `for` loops work. And what `range` and `choice` do.

If you are interested in computer science, please do take the time to try things for yourself and bang your head until you crack the problem open and solve it. Like all of us have done and do daily.

There is plenty of resources for learning python online.

Having said that, here is a solution:

```
import random


def main():
    file_size = random.randint(4,7)
    odd_nums = range(5,20,2)
    with open('numbers.txt', 'w') as f:
        for _ in range(file_size):
            n = random.choice(odd_nums)
            f.write('{}\n'.format(n))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice! is there anyway i can utilize you for a recourse if i need to? is there  private messaging on this site?

Comment: hahahahaha, yes there are chatrooms, although I seldom use them. But given the amount of time I have available (as you can tell by my answer I am a father) and the several timezones between us I think it would be pointless. Best of luck, and do spend some time on SO, it helps a lot

Comment: if you think my answer solves your problem correctly and better than others', please mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random 
def main(): 
    number_file= open('numbers.txt', 'w') 
    file_size = random.randint(4,7) 
    list = [0]*20
    for i in range(0,file_size):
        k = random.randint(5,19)
        while k%2 == 0:
            k = random.randint(5,19)
        list[k]=1
    for i in range(1,len(list)):
        if list[i] == 0:
            number_file.write("\n")
        else:
            number_file.write(str(i)+"\n")
    number_file.close()
main()
```